# Encoding java.lang.Class[T] and Vector[_ <: Object]

Tags: java, json, scala, generics, circe

When writing a RPC framework, we need to code the Request and Response class, here is my Request class:

```
trait Servicable {} // a marking Trait for the services

case class Request[T <: Servicable](
  id: String, 
  serviceClazz: Class[T],
  methodName: String, 
  paramTypes: Vector[Class[_]], 
  params: Vector[_ <: Object]
)
```

So I wonder how to serialize/deserialize the classes like this one? The main point is that `circe` seems not to provide Codec for `java.lang.Class[T]`, and the serialization/deserialization of dynamic generic collection objects like `Vector[_ <: Object]` is also difficult.

Anybody can give me a hand?

Comment: `circe` has no way to know what `Class[T]` is. For your purposes, you may need to provide the fully qualified class name, as a `String`. You would do the same for the `paramTypes` -- the class name as a `String` can be instantiated by the `deserialization` library.

Comment: @Bob, thanks for your quick reply. So do you have any advice? How can I encode this class to Json decently using circe or any other lib in Scala?

Comment: I notice that `circe` works with `Shapeless` to allow use of generics.

Comment: @Bob, so can you write a demo code for ser/des this class? I am not familiar with shapeless or scalaz...

Comment: I am going to say writing a decoder and encoder for `Class[T]` is reasonably easy, but for `Vector[_ <: Object]` is hopeless without doing evil things.

Comment: @Alexy So, no solution? No Scala specific json lib avaliable?